# ViewPager с фрагментами. Можно ли регулировать обработку поворота для разных фрагментов по-разному

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Имеется ViewPager c фрагментами в качестве вкладок. Один из фрагментов должен быть портрет-ориентирован. Все остальные должны крутиться при повороте экрана. Как это сделать? Интересует Android 4.4 и выше.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте в нужном вам фрагменте

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

в остальных фрагментах

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```